# Is there a tool for generating C headers from Rust modules?

Tags: rust

If you write a Rust library and you want to call it from C, you have to mark all the export functions with extern C and make sure everything uses the C ABI. But then you also have to write a header file by hand to include in your C code, and manually ensure that it is consistent with the Rust definitions, or Bad Things will happen. This seems both dangerous and tedious.

Is there a tool for generating C headers from Rust code? I've seen bindings that go the other way, for using C from Rust, and that's actually a harder problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is [a requested feature for Rust](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10530), but I haven't found any implementations.

---

**UPDATE:**

As @HameerAbbasi notes below, [cbindgen](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/) is the preferred tool for doing this now.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be used so that I can iron out the kinks, but [yes](http://github.com/Sean1708/rusty-cheddar).

Comment: It was forked by Mozilla: https://github.com/mozilla/moz-cheddar

Answer (score 4):

A more recent way to do this is https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen/, which seems to be actively maintained at the time of writing. The accepted answer from @hcs links to a GitHub issue that says that this should be tackled by an external tool.